MSI return 3010 on loop
I am trying to install the Audient EVO 4's (a USB audio interface) device drivers for Windows 11. The installer prompts disconnecting the device before continuing the installation process as well as "close all running applications". On continuing the installation, it stops at a point where the log reads "MSI return code 3010" which ideally means the installation is done with a pending system restart due to an interfering application. Once restart, the installer automatically opens up to continue, only to throw the same MSI status.
I have disabled all startup processes and tried running the .exe to install the drivers but I get into the same loop, with not successful installation.
I have also tried the installation in safe mode and ended up seeing the same "restart your device" pop up and the 3010 return code (I had to modify the registry to allow MSI Server to run in safe mode)
Please suggest what system processes may be interfering in an installation... the manufacturer's youtube video on setting up the drivers/device shows that a restart is not necessary (as does the installer).
